# tailwind doesn't want to show font

Tags: html, tailwind-css

here's my question. for learning purposes i am currently working on a website with tailwind installed with the CLI method. i downloaded a font and applied it in my configuration file like this:

```
fontFamily: {
      sans: ['"Dela Gothic One"', 'cursive'],
      serif: ['Graphik', 'sans-serif'],
    },
```

unfortunately, the font doesn't show up, even if i call the font

```
 <h1 class="name font-sans">bolliger et mabillard</h1>
```

any tips to make it work?

Comment: How does the generated CSS look like, is the font referenced like it should? Is this a font your user needs to have installed? If not, how is the font served, is it requested by the browser? Check all this in your dev tools.

Comment: Share the entire contents of your tailwind config file.

Comment: Are you supplying those fonts via tailwind from Google?

Comment: you mean looking atthe packages.json file i don't have even though i used the CLI method (whiwh should've generated it with packages-lock.json)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing single quotes declaring the fontFamily, I would try adding you font in `tailwind.config.js` like so:

```
fontFamily: {
      'sans': ['"Dela Gothic One"', 'cursive'],
      'serif': ['Graphik', 'sans-serif'],
    },
```

and it should then work.